# Using list compreshension with a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list-comprehension, list-comparison

I have a list of dictionaries (LDICT) and a list of strings (LS).  I would like to check to make sure that the items in LS are not the keys in any of the dictionaries in LDICT.  If they are, I would like to remove the item from LS.

I've figured out a way to do this with for loops but it is ugly and I am struggling to understand how I can achieve this using list comprehension.

See code below for the example using for loops:

```
for item in LDICT:
    for k, v in item.iteritems():
        if k in LS:
            LS.remove(k)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `any()` to check each word in `LS`:

```
[k for k in LS if not any((k in t) for t in LDICT)]
```

Comment: Good clean answer, although it can take a long time to run if LDICT contains many large dicts and LS is long. If spatial complexity is not an issue, my other answer below should typically run in time linear in the size of the involved data structures.

Comment: @InonPeled your solution with `set`s is indeed a good optimization for OP to consider. My intention was merely to "faithfully" reproduce the behavior of OP's current approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
forbidden_keys = set(key for dct in LDICT for key in dct)
filtered_list = [item for item in LST if item not in forbidden_keys]
```

Comment: This will throw a NameError. Think you meant `forbidden_keys = set(key for dct in LDICT for key in dct)`

Comment: Yeah, I wrote that without checking, the double for loop in comprehension expression sometimes gets me. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Create a combined sets of all keys that are in all dicts of `LDICT` and substract that from a set of your `LS`:

(Long way)

```
LDICT = [ {i:"" for i in range(k,k+20,3)} for k in range(0,100,20)]

LS = [x for x in range(100) if x%4 == 0]
print(LDICT)
print(LS)

all_keys = set(x for d in LDICT for x in d)
print(all_keys)

cleaned_keys = set(LS)-all_keys
print(cleaned_keys)
```

Output:

```
# LDICT
[{0: '', 3: '', 6: '', 9: '', 12: '', 15: '', 18: ''}, 
 {20: '', 23: '', 26: '', 29: '', 32: '', 35: '', 38: ''}, 
 {40: '', 43: '', 46: '', 49: '', 52: '', 55: '', 58: ''}, 
 {60: '', 63: '', 66: '', 69: '', 72: '', 75: '', 78: ''}, 
 {80: '', 83: '', 86: '', 89: '', 92: '', 95: '', 98: ''}]

 # LS
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 
 68, 72, 76, 80, 84, 88, 92, 96]

 # all_keys
 {0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52, 55, 58, 60,
  63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 80, 83, 86, 89, 92, 95, 98}

 # cleaned_keys
 {64, 96, 4, 36, 68, 8, 44, 76, 16, 48, 84, 24, 56, 88, 28}
```

You just need to make a list out of `cleaned_keys`.

Doku:

- [set.difference(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)